# System cannot find specified file Gradle Android

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have downloaded a project [from here](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android)

I have android studio, Git, Gradle installed on my system.
After I import the project , while gradle is syncing it says me

```
" Gradle Signal-Android-master project refresh failed "

Error : CreateProcesses error=2 , The system cannot find the file specified "
```

I have googled alot but could n't find anything helpful.

Which file ? it doesn't state anything , I have seen the IDE logs as well but nothing there, any help in this regard ?

Thanks

Comment: As you say, not much to go on. First, in Android Studio, I would go to 'File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle' and inspect the Gradle home path. Assuming you're on windows, it would be something like 'C:\Program File\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle--2.14.1`. Then I would go to File Explorer and make sure that path exists.

Comment: @AlLelopath the path is correct, problem appears to be with git

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get github dependency in you project. First you have to specify the repository in build.gradle and then add that dependency in you project.

What you can do for git repository

Step 1. Add the JitPack repository to your build file Add it in your build.gradle at the end of repositories:

https://jitpack.io

```
repositories {
// ...
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

Step 2. Add the dependency in the form

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
```

}